# Integrals over derived Harmonic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

It makes sense, based on a visual image (for example in Complex Analysis: Selected Topics
by Mario Gonzalez page 116) , for a harmonic function $\Omega:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that for simple, closed and smooth curves C

$\int_{C}^{} (\frac{\partial \Omega}{\partial x}dy - \frac{\partial \Omega}{\partial y}dx) = 0$

but is that always the case?

Comment: This follows from Green's theorem, $\displaystyle \int_{C} \frac{\partial \Omega}{\partial x}dy - \frac{\partial \Omega}{\partial y}dx = \int_R \left(\frac{\partial^2 \Omega}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 \Omega}{\partial y^2}\right)\,dx\,dy = 0$ (where, $R$ is the region bounded by $C$) for every simply connected subset $R$ implies $\Delta \Omega = 0$.

Comment: Thanks! Just the proof I was looking for. I actually skimmed over it earlier, but somehow without connecting the dots. The notation was different than what I am used to and I think it is a complicated proof!

Comment: This proof only works if we assume $\Omega \in C^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ (otherwise Green's identity cannot be applied). A slightly different but a bit more complicated proof works for the case when $\Omega \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$.

Comment: Thanks again! I realized that going through the proof again. By the way: Do you want to answer the question, or should I just close the question myself?

Comment: You can close the question if that answers your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @r9m pointed out in the comments section the assumption in the question follows from Green's theorem.